# How do I create a JSP link that executes a local jar file?

Tags: java, jsp, jar

I would just like to ask on how can I create a jsp link that runs a local jar file in my machine `(Location is C:\sample.jar)` when the link is pressed on the local web application.

So far I have tried all these approach but to no avail:

a. `href="file:///C:/sample.jar"`

b. `href="file://localhost/C:/sample.jar"`

Any response would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that with basic HTML. You'll have to use JSP, or some other form of controller. Even then, you may be restricted as to how you do it.

Comment: "Even then, you may be restricted as to how you do it" ---> Can you elaborate more on this one?

Comment: yes I am using jsp

Comment: If you link to a jar file, even a local one, the browser should NEVER just start it. The reason should be quite obvious.

Comment: @user3468299 Running a class file from a web context, i.e. within a web server, may be restricted compared to running the jar from the command line. You can call use a JSP file to access a jar, but it will probably need to already be loaded in the web context to allow you to access the code in question. You'll have to try it and see. But it's going to depend on the web server in question. I can't say if the code in question will run or not. Load your jar as part of a web app and call the method you require upon receiving an action from your web client. Try it for yourself, see if it works.

Comment: Caveat, just to be clear: My suggestion above will only work if the server is running on your local machine, of course. You can't do that generally speaking. The code can only be run on the SERVER machine, not the local one, unless the server is running on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

JSP stands for Java **Server** Pages. That means that the Java code they contain is executed on the server, not on the client.

On the client, a JSP can do no more than a simple HTML page.

Maybe you should use a [Java applet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet), not a JSP.

Applets will allow you to load jars in a browser. However, not local jars. That's not possible.

Comment: Java applets are dying - some browsers already refuse to execute them **unless** the certificate is a bought one. Applets had a good run ... but now its time to forget about them.

Comment: Do you have a better idea for loading a jar in a browser?

Comment: Yes : direct downloads via HTTPS/SSL and free (!) certificate. The download page could show an instruction on how to download & install Java and how to double-click the JAR ... which of course would have to have a proper manifest and mainclass-entry.

Comment: That's not exactly zero effort

Comment: Why, yes - indeed thats absolutely not 0 effort. Well observed. Welcome to the world of software development - if you want to do it *"the right way"* you need to invest a lot of effort.

Comment: Oh, you seem to know a lot about software development.

Comment: Yet again : well observed.

Comment: If he has a server running on his local machine, he could access a local library's code, but you're right regarding accessing a local file otherwise. The jar code must exist on the server, not the client, unless they're both the same. And, agreed on applets, they're pretty much dead and have been for quite some time: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/migratingfromapplets-2872444.pdf.